# NoClassDefFoundError ForkedBooter

Tags: java, maven, compilation, in-memory

I own a project for fast inmemory compilation at [src2jar](https://github.com/enexusde/source2runnablejar/tree/test-updated-surefire-version).

I have the problem that maven can not `clean test` successfully.

This is the test:

```
public void testOneSourceFile() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException,
        IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, SecurityException, InterruptedException {
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    DefaultSystemFileManager fileManager = new DefaultSystemFileManager(
            compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null));
    Iterable<String> options = Arrays.asList("-g:lines");
    JavaSource j = new JavaSource("package t; public class j{}", "j");
    JavaSource e = new JavaSource(
            "package t; public class e extends t{public static void main(String... args) throws javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException{System.out.println('d'); throw new javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(\"sdf\");}}",
            "e");
    compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, options, null, Arrays.asList(j, e)).call();
    compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, options, null, Arrays.asList(e, j)).call();
    fileManager.close();
}
```

This is the output:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Determined Maven Process ID 7960
[DEBUG] boot classpath:  C:\Users\Guest\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-booter\2.21.0\surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar  C:\Users\Guest\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-api\2.21.0\surefire-api-2.21.0.jar  C:\Users\Guest\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-logger-api\2.21.0\surefire-logger-api-2.21.0.jar  C:\Users\Guest\git\source2runnablejar2\target\test-classes  C:\Users\Guest\git\source2runnablejar2\target\classes  C:\Users\Guest\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-junit3\2.21.0\surefire-junit3-2.21.0.jar
[DEBUG] boot(compact) classpath:  surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar  surefire-api-2.21.0.jar  surefire-logger-api-2.21.0.jar  test-classes  classes  surefire-junit3-2.21.0.jar
[DEBUG] Forking command line: cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217\surefirebooter7632705165379384494.jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217 2018-04-16T11-44-32_148-jvmRun1 surefire5322226518055597260tmp surefire_04740175761818155392tmp"
[INFO] Running de.e_nexus.src2jar.test.JarOutputStreamTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.779 s - in de.e_nexus.src2jar.test.JarOutputStreamTest
[INFO] Running de.e_nexus.src2jar.test.OneSourceFileTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.642 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-16T11:44:35+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/212M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project source2runnablejar: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Guest\git\source2runnablejar2\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217\surefirebooter7632705165379384494.jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217 2018-04-16T11-44-32_148-jvmRun1 surefire5322226518055597260tmp surefire_04740175761818155392tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] Crashed tests:
[ERROR] de.e_nexus.src2jar.test.OneSourceFileTest
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217\surefirebooter7632705165379384494.jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217 2018-04-16T11-44-32_148-jvmRun1 surefire5322226518055597260tmp surefire_04740175761818155392tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] Crashed tests:
[ERROR] de.e_nexus.src2jar.test.OneSourceFileTest
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project source2runnablejar: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\Guest\git\source2runnablejar2\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217\surefirebooter7632705165379384494.jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217 2018-04-16T11-44-32_148-jvmRun1 surefire5322226518055597260tmp surefire_04740175761818155392tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
Crashed tests:
de.e_nexus.src2jar.test.OneSourceFileTest
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217\surefirebooter7632705165379384494.jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217 2018-04-16T11-44-32_148-jvmRun1 surefire5322226518055597260tmp surefire_04740175761818155392tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
Crashed tests:
de.e_nexus.src2jar.test.OneSourceFileTest
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\Guest\git\source2runnablejar2\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217\surefirebooter7632705165379384494.jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217 2018-04-16T11-44-32_148-jvmRun1 surefire5322226518055597260tmp surefire_04740175761818155392tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
Crashed tests:
de.e_nexus.src2jar.test.OneSourceFileTest
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217\surefirebooter7632705165379384494.jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217 2018-04-16T11-44-32_148-jvmRun1 surefire5322226518055597260tmp surefire_04740175761818155392tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
Crashed tests:
de.e_nexus.src2jar.test.OneSourceFileTest
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.throwException(SurefireHelper.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:354)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1008)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217\surefirebooter7632705165379384494.jar C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4719342102025273217 2018-04-16T11-44-32_148-jvmRun1 surefire5322226518055597260tmp surefire_04740175761818155392tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
Crashed tests:
de.e_nexus.src2jar.test.OneSourceFileTest
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
    ... 23 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Try using a later version of `maven-surefire-plugin`. `2.12.4` is ca. 6 years old. `2.21.0` is the current version.

Comment: Did you mean `2.21.0`?

Comment: Why don't you commit what you have so far in some branch so that people like me could play with it and maybe fix?

Comment: @lexicore Thats a good idea. Updated question to point to branch https://github.com/enexusde/source2runnablejar/tree/test-updated-surefire-version

Comment: I don't get the `NoClassDefFoundError` after switching `maven-surefire-plugin` version to `2.21.0`. The `OneSourceFileTest` fails, but I guess it's just a failing test.

Comment: @lexicore Please notice the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add `-DforkMode=never`.